# How to create directory and upload file inside it using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In this code I have a controller having name proposal.php where I want that when I upload a file onclick button it make directory and uploaded file will be save inside it. Now, directory has been created successfully but file are not uploaded inside it. So, how can I fix this problem ?Please help me.

controller: proposal.php

```
public function upload_file_folder()
{
    $folder_name = $this->input->post('account_name');
    mkdir('resource/proposal_data/'.$folder_name.'_proposal_'.date('Y-m-d').'',0777, true);
    $filename = $_FILES[$this->input->post('file1')]['name'];
    $path = FCPATH."resource/proposal_data/".$folder_name."_proposal_".date('Y-m-d')."";
    $move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->input->post('file1')]['tmp_name'],$path.$_FILES[$this->input->post('file1')]['name']);
    echo "upload";
}
```

view:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mk").bind("click",function(){
      file1 = $("#file1").val();
      account_name = $("#account_name").val();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:{"file1":file1, "account_name":account_name},
        url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/'); ?>purposal/upload_file_folder",
        success:function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1">
<button type="submit" name="mk" id="mk">upload</button>
```

Thank You

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: when I upload a file it create a new directory but file are not uploaded inside it and onclick button it show me error undefine index. but index name are not mention in alert. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    public function upload_file_folder(){
       $folder_name = $this->input->post('account_name');  
       if(!is_dir("uploads/gallery/".$folder_name ."/")) {
           mkdir("uploads/gallery/".$folder_name ."/");
       }

       $target_dir = "uploads/gallery/".$folder_name ."/";
       $target_file = $target_dir.$_FILES['gallery']['name'];

       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'],$target_file);
   }
```

Comment: have you change the directory path which in if condition. Because this code is tested. It was my mistake. in $target_dir there was a wrong variable i placed. So try now.

Comment: yes, I have I think somthing is wrong in my script @Chaitanya

Comment: I am trying this but it shows undefile index file1   public function upload_file_folder()
  {
   $folder_name = $this->input->post('account_name');  
   if(!is_dir("resource/proposal_data/".$folder_name ."/")) 
   {
      mkdir("resource/proposal_data/".$folder_name ."/");
   }
   $target_dir = "resource/proposal_data/".$folder_name ."/";
   $target_file = $target_dir.$_FILES['file1']['name'][$key];
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],$target_file);
  }    Please take a look in my script.

Comment: remove the [$key]. Sorry you need to upload single file. That wise i change my code for you. I have given this type answer in other question. But it was for multiple images upload.

Comment: For more help go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807076/unable-to-save-single-image-along-with-multiple-images-in-codeigniter/45809735#45809735